# Rotativa Unable to load the model View when using ViewAsPdf

Tags: asp.net, converters, rotativa

I'm developing a Web application using MVC (.NET 7.0), I need to convert a View with data to PDF, to do that I'm using Rotativa.

Problem is, when I'm calling my method to convert the View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ConvertToPdf", "Home", new { html = ViewData["html"] })">Convert to PDF</a>
```

The model is not loaded and an exception is thrown

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which is understandable as the code doesn't reach the action that loads my view data.

Here is my controller Action

```
public ActionResult ConvertToPdf()
    {
      return new ViewAsPdf("ListUsers", _listUsers);
    }
```

And this is the action to feed the list view I want to convert

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ListUsers()
{
    _listUsers = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
    return View(_listUsers);
}
```

Any Idea of how I can load data into my view when exporting it to PDF? I'm using *ViewAsPdf* as I'm running Rotativa.AspNETCOre nuget package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer by myself.

Just need to load data from my context

```
    var model = _context.Users.Select(u => new Users
    {
        Username = u.Username,
        OfficeLocation= u.OfficeLocation,
        ContractType = u.ContractType,
        UserDept = u.UserDept
    });
return new ViewAsPdf("ListUsers", model) { FileName = "PDF File.pdf"};
```

The PDF conversion of the view works pretty well.